# Windows 10 GDAL Install (Binaries): Cannot find 'gdal-data' files (although path is set!) - what have I done wrong?

Tags: gdal, installation, windows

**Summary:** I have installed GDAL with Python bindings on Windows 10, using the binaries from GIS internals. I have ensured I added all the path variables. `gdalinfo --version` reports a version correctly, however when I use `gdalinfo <filename.tif> -mm` I get most of the expected output, but warnings regarding files in the gdal-data folder e.g. `Warning 1: Cannot find pcs.csv`.

What have I done wrong?

---

*I am aware there are several similar questions to this, but I can't find any that have my exact issues. Also, I have seen in answers to other questions the recommendation to use OSGeo4W, however I would like to fix my current install if possible.*

---

**Details:**

1. I installed GDAL on my 64-bit Windows 10 system by following these instructions:
   https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows and these binaries: https://www.gisinternals.com/release.php
2. I checked the binaries and there don't appear to be any yet for the latest Python release, so I uninstalled my 3.9.x version and installed 3.7.9, for which there are binaries. I downloaded the core binaries and python bindings corresponding to the correct version and installed them.
3. As per the instructions, I added the GDAL path and the `GDAL_DATA` and `GDAL_DRIVER_PATH` environment variables. I also checked the Python directory had been added to the path.
4. I tested the install with `gdalinfo --version` and received:
   `GDAL 2.4.4, released 2020/01/08`
   which I took to mean the install was correct. Python was similarly checked.
5. I then proceeded with the tutorial in https://medium.com/planet-stories/a-gentle-introduction-to-gdal-part-1-a3253eb96082. I downloaded the test file `CANYrelief1-geo.tif` and entered the following command in the windows terminal, as instructed: `gdalinfo CANYrelief1-geo.tif -mm`
6. I receive the following output:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: CANYrelief1-geo.tif
Size is 2800, 2800
Warning 1: Cannot find pcs.csv
Warning 1: Cannot find datum.csv or gdal_datum.csv
Warning 1: Cannot find ellipsoid.csv
Warning 1: Cannot find prime_meridian.csv
Coordinate System is:
LOCAL_CS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["unknown",
            SPHEROID["unretrievable - using WGS84",6378137,298.257223563]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (-12249462.599999999627471,4629559.794860946945846)
Pixel Size = (13.284000000000001,-13.285397060378999)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2017:04:01 20:24:57
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Adobe Photoshop CC (Macintosh)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=72
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=72
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-12249462.600, 4629559.795)
Lower Left  (-12249462.600, 4592360.683)
Upper Right (-12212267.400, 4629559.795)
Lower Right (-12212267.400, 4592360.683)
Center      (-12230865.000, 4610960.239)
Band 1 Block=2800x31 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
    Computed Min/Max=149.000,255.000
Band 2 Block=2800x31 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
    Computed Min/Max=133.000,255.000
Band 3 Block=2800x31 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
    Computed Min/Max=100.000,255.000
```

I do not receive the expected output (as detailed in the tutorial), and most obviously I receive several warnings, which correspond to files in the gdal-data folder - which are there, I've checked! The path is also in place so why can't they be found?

```
Warning 1: Cannot find pcs.csv
Warning 1: Cannot find datum.csv or gdal_datum.csv
Warning 1: Cannot find ellipsoid.csv
Warning 1: Cannot find prime_meridian.csv
```

Comment: Do you need Python bindings? If you don't just download https://download.gisinternals.com/sdk/downloads/release-1928-x64-gdal-mapserver.zip, unzip into for example c:\gdal, run `sdkshell.bat` and you will have working GDAL installation (dev version).

Comment: That is a good point, which I hadn't considered! I was just following the tutorial instructions and assumed I did, as I'm new to all of this, but I will try your method - thank you. I'll let you know if it works - if so, would you like to form it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @user30184 - I used the method you described, and it has solved the initial problem, however generated some new ones. The SDKShell.bat install only seems to apply temporarily - I have to re-do it every time I open the cmd (even if I have run as admin). Is this normal? Also I am now getting errors relating to proj: `ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create: unrecognized format / unknown name
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
'+proj=moll` I'm happy to format this as a new question but if it is a simple fix perhaps you could advise here. If you want to make it an answer please do. Thanks.

Comment: The sdkshell.bat edits your PATH. You can open the file with text editor and make the same changes into your default PATH but that is not a GIS problem. Or you can simply create a shortcut for sdksell.bat. About the problem with using GDAL and Proj you must give more details. I do not think I have answered your initial question. There seems to be some version mismatch or several GDALs on your computer if you installed the newest GDAL and your computer shows version 2.4.4.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The 2.4.4 version of GDAL was what I initially installed using the binaries, that was the most recent stable version that matched my Python release, as far as I could tell. I uninstalled this before trying your method, after which it reported `GDAL 3.4.0dev` etc so I think that is fine. The proj thing I have solved - it was simply a matter of enclosing the relevant commands in double rather than single quotes!

Comment: There must have been a problem with setting `GDAL_DATA` but if you have removed that 2.4.4. version it is not reasonable to spend time for that.

Comment: When referencing earlier Q&As from this site please always include links to them to save any potential answerer having to try and find them before trying to answer your question.